# How to merge waypoints or tracks into a single block?

Tags: overpass-api

When downloading routes from OverpassTurbo as KML files, I end up with two blocks: One is made of "`<Placemark><LineString><coordinates>`", and the other of "`<Placemark><Point><coordinates>`".

To merge those as a single route, I checked Viking and JOSM but didn't find how do it. I also tried GPSVisualizer, but this is what I get:
[image]

Does someone know of a way to merge ways or tracks into a single route?

Answer (score -1):

I have recently been using overpass Turbo and am wondering if exporting the data as gpx would give you a usuable track. If you must use kml, there are plenty of web sites that can convert gpx to kml.

Comment: Welcome to our site!  Are you proposing this as an answer or trying to ask a question?

Comment: Sorry, I see that I have misinterpreted the question.